# Facebook comments do not appear on every post

Tags: wordpress, facebook-comments

I've added the Facebook app to my wordpress blog and the comment box appears on some of my old posts but not my newer posts. They were all written the same way on the same blog, why does the comment box show up selectively? How do I make it appear on all posts?

My site is www.heymouser.com if you would like to take a look at it.

Comment: Looking at http://www.heymouser.com/new-years-eve-neil-hamburger/#more-1471 source code, I can't find the code for the comments plugin. 

If you use a 3rd party plugin to automatically insert this, I would assume it's an error on their side.